Cant install browsers for playwright
I'm new to playwright, I tried initializing it in project and it failed using VS code command and console commands.
When I try to use npx playwright install I got this error log:
0 verbose cli /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/22.5.1/bin/node /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@10.8.2
2 info using node@v22.5.1
3 silly config load:file:/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc
4 silly config load:file:/Users/rostyslavpopov/WorkProjects/playwright/.npmrc
5 silly config load:file:/Users/rostyslavpopov/.npmrc
6 silly config load:file:/opt/homebrew/etc/npmrc
7 verbose title npm exec playwright install
8 verbose argv "exec" "--" "playwright" "install"
9 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:/Users/rostyslavpopov/.npm/_logs/2024-07-28T13_20_13_157Z-
10 verbose logfile /Users/rostyslavpopov/.npm/_logs/2024-07-28T13_20_13_157Z-debug-0.log
11 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 1 files
12 silly logfile done cleaning log files
13 silly packumentCache heap:4345298944 maxSize:1086324736 maxEntrySize:543162368
14 verbose stack Error: could not determine executable to run
14 verbose stack     at getBinFromManifest (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/libnpmexec/lib/get-bin-from-manifest.js:17:23)
14 verbose stack     at exec (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/libnpmexec/lib/index.js:202:15)
14 verbose stack     at async Npm.exec (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:207:9)
14 verbose stack     at async module.exports (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli/entry.js:74:5)
15 verbose pkgid playwright@1.0.0
16 error could not determine executable to run
17 verbose cwd /Users/rostyslavpopov/WorkProjects/playwright
18 verbose os Darwin 23.5.0
19 verbose node v22.5.1
20 verbose npm  v10.8.2
21 verbose exit 1
22 verbose code 1
23 error A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/rostyslavpopov/.npm/_logs/2024-07-28T13_20_13_157Z-debug-0.log

Also, im not sure if this is correct behaviour, but my node_modules modules are empty.
I tried deleting node_modules and running commands again, deleted git hooks(they are not present but i still tried) but no luck resolving the issue.

The init command is first used for installing the browsers, npx playwright install is only for upgrading https://playwright.dev/docs/intro#installing-playwright

`npm i -D @playwright/test
install supported browsers
npx playwright install`
this is a second way of doing it, the first commands goes fine for me, but the second one where it fails, even if i do npm init playwright@latest, its still gonna fail with same rror on the process that is launched by npx playwright install
@OneCricketeer
